# How can I set HTML code inside select <option> in React?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to output pretty fractions inside my  options, ¼ ½ ¾ but it's displaying the "&frac 14;" as strings.

How can I get the JSX to interpret my optionContent and render the HTML, not as a string?

optionValue = "4.25"
optionContent = "4 ¾"
{optionContent}

[image]

Comment: can you show the code how you apply option in JSX ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using the html-react-parser;

**Example:**
https://codesandbox.io/s/parsing-html-react-zlmwj

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Parser from "html-react-parser";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [options, setOption] = useState(1);
  const [listOptions] = useState([
    { id: 1, desc: "4 &frac14;" },
    { id: 2, desc: "4 &frac12;" },
    { id: 3, desc: "4 &frac34;" }
  ]);

  function handleSelect(e) {
    const selected = e.target.value;
    setOption(selected);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Example parsing html in React</h1>

      <select value={options} onChange={e => handleSelect(e)}>
        {listOptions.map(option => (
          <option key={option.id} value={option.id}>
            {Parser(option.desc)}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
}
```